# Can you do a Full Install with Windows 7 Upgrade Media?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

Can you do a Full Install with Windows 7 Upgrade Media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Full install if you only have the Upgrade media. Microsoft says you can't, but the following link explains otherwise.

http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like for some people it just works, however for others you have to go through the same hacks you had to do with Vista, such as installing a "trial" version, and then upgrading your trial.  There is a nice guide at the [Windows SuperSite](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp) with a bunch of things to try.